# Find substring in string when selecting from the MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I take text that is a \n delimited string and output every row that contains a certain substring?

For example:
DB:

```
product | keywords
-------------------
test    |  test\ntest1\ntest2\ntest3
test1   |  test\nblah\nblah
test2   |  tst\nblah\nblah
test3   |  testr\nblah\nblah
```

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE
```

How would I write the WHERE clause to pull product test and test1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set('test', replace(keywords, '\n', ',')) > 0
or find_in_set('test1', replace(keywords, '\n', ',')) > 0
```

But actually you will be better off by changing the table design and don't store multiple values in a single colum.

Comment: Ah I believe I misworded it, but this looks like it would work, if it was a dynamic variable I could do something like,               where find_in_set($var, replace(keywords, '\n', ',')) > 0, and use php to run the query correct?

Comment: I will keep in mind to change the db structure, I am just on a timelimit to get this task done, I am going to, however, bookmark this page because you are right, I should link the product_id to another table and use an entry for each keyword

Comment: Minor point, but if your substring can contain a comma you probably need to replace that with some kind of place holder before you replace you other delimiter with a comma.

Comment: Excellent point, luckily it can't contain a comma, the db needs some restructuring done, which I plan to do in the future, thanks everyone for your input :)

Comment: If it does need a comma, I could write some php code that replaces a keywork such as (comma) with a comma once pulled from the database, would take only slight modification to the sql query

Comment: Afraid if the strings contain commas then the query as it stands wouldn't work. FIND_IN_SET('2,3', '1,2,3,4,5,6') returns 0 so the query wouldn't find anything to pull from the database and change in php. You could do the change in the query with something like _FIND_IN_SET(REPLACE('test', ',', '######'), REPLACE(REPLACE(keywords, ',', '######'), '\n', ','))_ (assuming no string will contain ######). Hopefully this won't be an issue though.